# Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$table

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is my controller ..

```
class Customer extends CI_controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Customer_model');
}
public function create()
{

        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('office_phone', 'Phonenumber', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fax', 'Faxno.', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Mailaddress', 'required');

    $data = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),

        'address' => $this->input->post('address'),

        'phoneno' => $this->input->post('office_phone'),

        'fax' => $this->input->post('fax'),

        'email' => $this->input->post('email')
    );


    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('templates/header');  
        $this->load->view('master/customer',$data);
    }
    else
    {

        $this->Customer_model->register($data);
        $this->load->library('session');
       //$this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'New Contact has been added');
             //redirect(current_url());
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('templates/success');
    }
    $this->load->library('pagination');
     $this->load->library('table');



      // Config setup
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/customer/';
    $config['total_rows'] = 20;
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    // I added this extra one to control the number of links to show up at each page.
    $config['num_links'] = 5;
    // Initialize
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);


      $data1 = $this->db->get('registration');
      $header = array('Name', 'Address', 'phoneno','fax','email');
       $this->table->set_heading($header);
       $this->load->view('master/customer',$data1);
       }
}
```

This is my view part..

```
<div id='results'>
<?php  echo $this->table->generate($data1); ?>
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
</div>
```

while running iam getting an error message like this

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$table
>
> Filename: master/Customer.php
>
> Line Number: 44
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function generate() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_2.1.3\application\views\master\Customer.php
>   on line 44

Any body please tell me what is the problem.i am new to codeignator..

Answer (score 7):

When in the view, call `get_instance()` to get the CodeIgniter instance. From there, you can access the `table` property of the object, call the method you need.

```
<div id='results'>
<?php $CI =& get_instance(); ?>
<?php echo $CI->table->generate($data1); ?>
<?php echo $CI->pagination->create_links(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Customer::$table

Filename: master/Customer.php is the error getting now..

Answer (score 1):

i would like to recommend you this:

`<?php $CI =& get_instance(); ?>`

use `$CI` instead of `$this` in your view, and see it is working or not..

Answer (score 0):

Try to load `table` library in your constructior

```
public function __construct()
{
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->model('Customer_model');
     $this->load->library('table');
}
```

if it still give same error then load this `table` library into autoload file
like this

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('table');
```

hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

only one line your needed

```
$this->load->library('table');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','table');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.