# Style CodeIgniter "human name" in form validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to apply custom general style to all the "human names" in the CodeIgniter `set_rules` method of the form validation class:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(<name of field>, <human name>, <rules>);
```

Say I want to make all "human names" in boldface, I know that I can do:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(<name of field>, <strong>human name</strong>, <rules>);
```

However this is difficult to manage once the number of fields to style gets larger.

Is there are way to access it using something like the `set_error_delimeters`?

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimeters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
```

wherein I can just set the delimeters for this "human name" or 2nd parameter in the `set_rules` method?

Currently there is no (at least *explicitly* discussed) way to do this from the [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-error-messages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the error delimiters of the human name?

You want this change made in the [extended `form_validation` class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160610/extending-form-validation-in-codeigniter) so you don't have to declare it again in all your validation classes?

If both yes, [Chris has your back with this great solution](http://chris-schmitz.com/changing-default-error-delimiters-in-codeigniter/)!

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_error_prefix = '<p class="error">';
        $this->_error_suffix = '</p>';
    }
}
```

This does not have to use the [`protected $CI` magic thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15615679/3717115) so we are good here.

Answer (score 2):

You can change set_rules functions of form_validation library.You need to change label parameter of this function. Just look into set_rules function in this library. change this line 
$label = ($label === '') ? $field : $label;

surround the $field and $label which are  after ? by you delimeters.

You can override it or modify core library function or create new function in validation library to set delimeters for human names.